# Using VLOOKUP in Calculated Field in Google Sheets Pivot Table is unstable and gives #REF! error - but not consistently

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, vlookup

I have this Pivot table where I Want to look up a text representation of a code that is human readable. I am thus adding a value as a calculated field. This is the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(Season,Dropdowns!L3:M50,2,FALSE)
```

And this works fine! Or... so I thought, after just some seconds or minutes (seemingly at random), I get a ton of #REF! errors, and when I go int the Pivot table settings, the formula now looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(Season,#REF!,2,FALSE)
```

So somehow Google Sheets suddenly cannot "find" the Dropdowns!L3:M50 range, even though it is definitely there and nothing has happened to it...

Bug?

Answer (score 1):

As Carlo mentioned, there seems to be a bug in Google Sheets that makes absolute references in VLOOKUPs in pivot table calculated fields break. However, after some experimenting, I've found a way to get around it: **named ranges.**

If you go to <kbd>Data</kbd> → <kbd>Named Ranges</kbd>, you can assign your range a name – in this particular case, you could name `Dropdowns!L3:M50`, say, `all_dropdowns`, and then make your VLOOKUP `=VLOOKUP(Season, all_dropdowns, 2, FALSE)`. For some reason, that works without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Been able to replicate the issue exactly in a pivot table.
Looks like Google Sheet tries to update the formula continuosly and classify it as a circular reference, giving you a #ref as soon as the update runs in background.

I have been able to fix it: go to Files, Setting of the WorkFile, and then hit the second tab, "Calculus" (or Formula, sorry I have the Italian text) and then "Active iterative calculus" but with just 1 iteration; this way even if the formula crashed (as it will does), the value are not updated.

[image] [image]

[image]

EDIT: after some other testing, i found out that calculated field in pivot table does not like absolute references to cell; so, if it's applicable in your case, don't use the absolute cell range (es. "H1:J99") but instead the name of the field that you need to "look up" (es. in my case, Fruit)

[image]